# FLASK & Exernal Data

Tags: python, flask

I'm using Anaconda and setup the venv w/ **python 3.5**, but can easily change the version if needed -- running on **windows 10**

My Goal is to create a sharable file with the following layout:

```
shared_folder/
 ├── appLauncher.exe
 ├── config.py
 └── user_data/
     ├── images/
     └── database.db
```

Where the executable reads the config.py file and the config.py file directs the executable to read data from the user_data folder. (For now, I'm not using the config file, but instead hard coding the paths -- just trying to get it working)

my current directory looks like this:

```
shared_folder/
├── WebApp/
│    ├── static/
│    │    ├── css/
│    │    └── js/
│    ├── templates/
│    ├── __init__.py
│    └── routes.py
├── appLauncher.py
├── config.py
└── user_data/
     ├── images/
     └── database.db
```

I'm struggling with two issues (and am posting this as two questions):

**1. How can I direct flask to look outside of the static folder and read data from the user_data folder? For both the sqlite DB and the images?**

[2. How can I package this using pyinstaller to allow me to reference config.py and the user_data files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53639398/packaging-flask-with-external-config)

current torn down example (only trying to pull in one image from user_data):

appLauncher.py:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
  from WebApp import app
  app.run()
```

static/css/play.css:

```
.helloworld {
  font-size: 80px;
}
```

templates/index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>my App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href={{ url_for("static", filename="css/play.css") }}>
    <div class="helloworld">Hello World!</div>
    <!-- <img src='{{ url_for("static", filename="flask.jpg") }}'> -->
    <img src='{{ img }}'>
    <img src='{{ img|safe }}'>
  </body>
</html>
```

WebApp/**init**.py:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

import WebApp.routes
```

WebApp/routes.py:

```
from WebApp import app
from flask import render_template, url_for, send_file

@app.route("/")
@app.route("/index")
def hello():
    return render_template(
        "index.html",
        img = send_file(r"C:\Users\EvanS\Desktop\FlaskExternalEXE\user_data\flask.jpg")
    )
```